# Finding eigenvvalue and eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given a matrix $A= \bigg({} \matrix{10 & 7 \\-14 &-11} \bigg{)}$ and eigenvalue $3$. My elite mission is to find the treacherous basis for the eigenspace.

I used the $(A -eI)=v$ where $e$ is the eigenvalue and $I$ is the identity matrix. I then obtained the reduced row echelon form or the resulting matrix to find non-zero solutions for $v$. However the matrix came back with no free variables so all solutions are $0$. The book I am reading from says the answer is $\{[-1;1]\}$. How is that possible.

Doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system you should solve to find the eigenvectors is
$$
(A - 3 I)v = 0 \implies\\
\pmatrix{7&7\\-14&-14} \pmatrix{v_1\\v_2} = \pmatrix{0\\0}
$$
What is the solution to this system?

Comment: since there are a lot of solutions, maybe someone can not see a particular one

Comment: Ah, it was dumb of me I messed up the signs.